# Boolean operation for 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to get a result of OR between in two list like

```
a = [0,0,1,1]
b = [0,1,0,1]
output = [0,1,1,1]
```

I have tried `output = a or b` but the answer isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

You can map `a` and `b` to `operator.or_`:

```
from operator import or_
output = map(or_, a, b)
```

`output` becomes:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = map(lambda x, y: bool(x or y), a, b)
```

Result:

```
output == [False, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

note that `or` or the binary operator `|` could be used here:

```
a = [0,0,1,1]
b = [0,1,0,1]

a_or_b = [aa | bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
# this also works:
# a_or_b = [aa or bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
print(a_or_b)  # [0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'numpy' library and take the maximum over the corresponding axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,0,1,1], [0,1,0,1]])
np.amax(a, axis=0)
```